# How can I use a value of a file, as a parameter in a bash shell script?

Tags: bash

I am programming in **bash** and I want to call some of the results, as variables, so they can be printed at the title of some graphs. 
In my script I choose some elements of an array and put each one of them in a single file.dat. For example:

```
cat Variables.dat | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}' > Variable1.dat
```

Now, the file Variable1.dat, contains only a single value and I want to use this value as a variable in my script. I tried several things like:

```
Var1="$Variable1.dat"    or  Var1=$(echo "$Variable1.dat" )
```

and they do not work. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `var1=$(cat Variable1.dat)`?

Comment: @tripleee it is not a dublicate.  I honestly do not understand how the answers given in: Read a file into a variable, could help me. And anyway you should also agree that the comments of acro444 and of Xen2050 are really helpful and really clear for every reader that wants to make a value and not a hole file a variable.

Comment: Aside: You can give the input file directly to awk to avoid the pipe. Otherwise you have a [Useless Use of Cat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat). Instead, try `Var1=$(awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}' Variables.dat)`. Even in @arco444's example `Var1=$(<Variable1.dat)` would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you might be able to skip the splitting an array into individual files, and just use

```
Var1=$(cat Variables.dat | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}')
```

Or if you'd prefer, the no-cat version, letting `awk` read the file itself (though for longer piped commands, leaving the `cat` in the beginning could be more clear & editable in the future). And I've probably spent more time typing this sentence than you'll ever waste in running extra `cat` commands too ;-)

```
Var1=$(awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}' Variables.dat)
```

Comment: perhaps...  I pasted Maria's existing code :) I'll throw up the cat-less version

Comment: :-D thanks again @Hen2050, I thought that it is obligatory to put cat, since I also thought that awk can not read the file itself :-| .